# Падает Spring, JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdk11

Использую `JDK 11`

Помогите понять, чего не хватает спрингу?

spring-db.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="false">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/initDB.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script encoding="utf-8" location="classpath:db/populateDB.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <!-- Choose profile from (hsqldb, postgres) and (jdbc,datajpa,jpa) -->

    <beans profile="postgres">
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/postgres.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
              p:driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              p:url="${database.url}"
              p:username="${database.username}"
              p:password="${database.password}"
        />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="tomcat">
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/bityard"/>
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/tomcat.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="jdbc">
        <context:component-scan base-package="ru.bityard.repository.jdbc" scoped-proxy="targetClass"/>
        <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="namedJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
            <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="jpa,datajpa">
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
              p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
              p:packagesToScan="ru.bityard.pojo">
<!--            p:persistenceUnitName="persistenceUnit">-->

            <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
                <map>
                    <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).FORMAT_SQL}" value="${hibernate.format_sql}"/>
                    <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).USE_SQL_COMMENTS}"
                           value="${hibernate.use_sql_comments}"/>

                    <!--https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/userguide/chapters/caching/Caching.adoc#caching-provider-jcache-->
                    <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).CACHE_REGION_FACTORY}" value="org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory"/>
                    <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory).PROVIDER}" value="org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider"/>
                    <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE}" value="true"/>
                    <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).USE_QUERY_CACHE}" value="false"/> <!--default-->

                </map>
            </property>

            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}">
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven/>

        <!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
              p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>


    </beans>

    <!--<beans profile="jpa">-->
        <!--<context:component-scan base-package="ru.javawebinar.**.ru.bityard.repository.jpa"/>-->
    <!--</beans>-->



    <beans profile="datajpa">
        <context:component-scan base-package="ru.bityard.repository.datajpa"/>
        <jpa:repositories base-package="ru.bityard.repository.datajpa"/>
        <!--<context:component-scan base-package="ru.bityard.repository.jdbc"/>-->
    </beans>

</beans>
```

Падает при запуске с ошибкой:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1728)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
09-Jul-2019 23:20:01.215 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Comment: .xml в 2к19?))) Сильно!

Comment: @Antonio112009 сочетание аннотаций с xml-конфигурацией - самый широко применяемый подход на сегодняшний день.

Comment: Ну прожать - поржали, а помочь?

Comment: Покажите pom.xml